# Who called my RPC?

Tags: windows, rpc, midl

I'm building an Microsoft RPC server and I was wondering if there is a way to determine which user called the RPC function? (meaning, which user is running the process that invoked the RPC method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is a more efficient method, but one solution is to call [RpcImpersonateClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375720%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), OpenThreadToken, and then [RpcRevertToSelf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378431%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or RpcRevertToSelfEx as appropriate.

You can get the user SID from the token with GetTokenInformation and convert it to a username if desired with LookupAccountSid.